# Linq To Sql: The member Date has no supported translation to SQL

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Consider a class that's used to represent the results of a `GroupBy()`. The goal of the code is to replace a stored procedure that would have grouped and counted a bunch of rows by the `Created datetime` field.

```
public class Statistic
{
    public int NumRecords { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the code raising an exception/warning:

```
//returning an IEnumerable<Statistic>
return db.MyTable
            .GroupBy(x => x.CreatedOn.Date ) //precision of date, not time.
            .Select(x => new Statistic(x.Key, x.Count()) ) //custom object
            .OrderBy(x => x.Date);
```

The exception:

> The member Date has no supported
>   translation to SQL

When I refactor the code to load into a `var`, the exception/warning is generated on the `OrderBy()`.

**Question**: How can I avoid this exception using Linq To Sql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the query wasn't being executed and loaded into a variable when I had expected it.

The following will evaluate and run properly as expected.

```
IEnumerable<Statistic> stats = db.MyTable           
        .GroupBy(x => x.CreatedOn.Date )
        .Select(x=> new Statistic(x.Key, x.Count()) );


    return stats.OrderBy(x=>x.Date);
```

Answer (score 9):

I've run into this before when using the non-default constructor. If you use an [object initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) instead, Linq to Sql can figure out the mapping:

```
return db.MyTable
            .GroupBy(x => x.CreatedOn.Date ) //precision of date, not time.
            .Select(x => new Statistic{Date = x.Key, NumRecords = x.Count()} ) //custom object
            .OrderBy(x => x.Date);
```